# htaccess: check Image exist in specfic sub folder, if not show other image

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have no idea how to work in htaccess.

I have 2 folders in named as **city** and **country** inside **myhostname.com/download** folder,

Now I want to check only in **city** folder that "**myhostname.com/download/city/(somefiename).png**" exist or not,If this image not present in city folder show "**myhostname.com/download/city/no_image.png**".

Now I have managed to clear step 1  i.e. check Image exist in folder, if not show other image.

But how do I perform check for specific folder
like if put url "**myhostname.com/download/country/(somefiename).png**" browser should show **404 Error**

And if I put  url "**myhostname.com/download/city/(somefiename).png**" browser should show "**myhostname.com/download/city/no_image.png**".

I have to perform restriction to perform this operation uing htaccess.
I have my .htaccess file in root dir.

**Edit**: my .htaccess code

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/download/city/ -d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/download/city/(.*).png !-f
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /download/city/no-img.png [R,L]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please share your `.htaccess` code so we can see what you have done already.

Comment: Am so sorry for the late reply @Mike. I have edited my question and added  my .htaccess rules please help me.